# Trying to extract data from a file, then calculate two different averages from the file, and it keeps turning up 0.0, what do i do?

Tags: python, list, file-io, python-3.x, average

This program asks for the name of a file with weather data, like rettet_verdata_florida.txt. It then opens the file, and asks for the name of the file you want the specific data to be written into. It also asks for the year.

It is then supposed to read in the data for the different months of that year(which is separated by a \t in the text file), put the sums for the months in "sum_temp" and "sum_wind", and calculate the average while printing it out to both the file and the screen. But the average ends up being 0.0 for each month, even though it should work fine.

Here is some of the list:

```
Stnr    Dato    DD06    DD12    DD18    FFM FXM POM TAM UUM
50540   07.01.1957  150 170 170 6.2 8.8 1010.6  6.3 94
50540   08.01.1957  160 160 200 7.2 9.8 1001.8  8.0 99
50540   09.01.1957  290 200 160 8.1 13.3    990.2   5.7 91
50540   10.01.1957  300 360 350 12.7    15.4    1008.2  2.8 87
50540   11.01.1957  0   200 160 3.8 10.4    1015.1  1.7 98
50540   12.01.1957  0   330 340 5.1 10.4    995.0   5.0 96
50540   13.01.1957  350 130 60  6.5 12.3    1018.2  1.6 54
50540   14.01.1957  0   130 150 3.1 7.0 1033.0  -2.8    69
```

Here is the code:

```
def year_avg():

    #Asks for the file name to be opened, file name for storage, and year (buffer against error).
    file_opening = input("Write the file to be opened (with .txt): ") or "rettet_verdata_florida.txt"
    file_open = open(file_opening, "r")
    writing_file = input("Which file do you want it written to, sir?: ") or "file_for_data.txt"
    year = float(input("And which year do you want it from?: "))

    #Constants and sums
    number_of_days = [0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    sum_temp = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    sum_wind = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

    #For leap years
    if year % 4 == 0:
        number_of_days[2] = 29


    #In case the teacher tries anything funny
    if (writing_file == "rettet_verdata_florida.txt" or "verdata_kirkenes.txt" or "verdata_florida.txt"):
        writing_file = "file_for data.txt"


    #Makes the writing file, and picks the data for that year
    store_data = open(writing_file, "w")

    for line in file_open:
        try:
            split_numbers = line.split('\t')
            date_info = split_numbers[1].split('.')
            year_of_line = float(date_info[2])
            month_of_line = float(date_info[1])

            if year_of_line == year:
                sum_temp[int(month_of_line)] += float(split_numbers[8])
                sum_wind[int(month_of_line)] += float(split_numbers[5])

        except Exception:
            pass


    #Prints everything out, plus stores it in the file specified in "writing_file"
    year_in_comma = (float(year))/10000
    print("Dato\tTAM\tFFM")

    for i in range(1, 13):
        print(i + year_in_comma, sum_temp[i] / number_of_days[i] , sum_wind[i] / number_of_days[i], sep = "\t", file = store_data) 
        print(i + year_in_comma, sum_temp[i] / number_of_days[i] , sum_wind[i] / number_of_days[i], sep = "\t")


    store_data.close()
    file_open.close()
```

Comment: Could you just copy and paste some of the data from that file, instead of taking a screenshot of it?

Comment: tried, but it comes out all jumbled :/

Comment: What if you put it inside of `<pre>` tags? Like `<pre>YOUR DATA</pre>`?

Comment: nice, didn't think of that

Comment: What is happening in that block where you snarf all of the exceptions?

Comment: it's supposed to catch the first line in the text file, which is text, and then continue with adding up the numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the problem here is: you have:

```
year = float(input("And which year do you want it from?: "))
```

and `year` is a `float`.
Then later you have:

```
date_info = split_numbers[1].split('.')
year_of_line = date_info[2]
month_of_line = date_info[1]

if year_of_line == year:
```

where `year_of_line` is `str`, and that is condition is always false. Your data, as a result, are always just zeros. If you have been using `python 2.x`, this problems may be easier to detect, as your result will all be `0` instead of `0.`

Comment: I tried making year_of_line and month_of_line a float, but it still returns 0.0, doesn't seem to take away the problem

Comment: Shouldn't be. Using the data you provided above, I got `Dato TAM FFM
(1.1957, 0.9129032258064517, 1.7000000000000002)`. Of course in that data, all are from Jan.

Comment: Maybe there are something wrong with your data. Try: adding a `file_open.readline()` before the `for line in file_open` loop and get rid of the `try: except`. You may see some errors pop up.

Comment: I found out, it was a newbie problem...I had set both year and year_of_line as float, but year still kept popping up as 1957, while year_of_line became 1957.0, but thanks for the help everyone!